# chkdsk c: /r in CMD does not reset dirty bit

Tags: windows-10, chkdsk

my C-drive is dirty when I check it in CMD. When I schedule a chkdsk scan for the next time I reboot, it does tell me it is checking and fixing the disc problem. However, within seconds (without showing a progress bar), this process is over and my computer is booted. When I recheck, my C-drive still remains dirty.

Running Windows 10 on 64bit.